# Runtime error while building Mongocxx driver on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I tried to follow [this](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html#preparing-a-build-from-a-git-repository-clone) on my Ubuntu 21.04, But I was getting the following error when I try to build using the Make command:

[ 39%] Downloading crypt_shared
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/styles/Softwares/mongo-c-driver-1.22.0/build/mongodl.py", line 700, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/styles/Softwares/mongo-c-driver-1.22.0/build/mongodl.py", line 679, in main
target = args.target or infer_target()
File "/home/styles/Softwares/mongo-c-driver-1.22.0/build/mongodl.py", line 86, in infer_target
return _infer_target_os_rel()
File "/home/styles/Softwares/mongo-c-driver-1.22.0/build/mongodl.py", line 127, in _infer_target_os_rel
raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: We don't know how to map 'ubuntu' version '21.10' to a distribution download target. Please contribute!
gmake[2]: *** [src/libmongoc/CMakeFiles/get-crypt_shared.dir/build.make:80: src/libmongoc/mongo_crypt_v1.so] Error 1
gmake[1](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html#preparing-a-build-from-a-git-repository-clone): *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2041: src/libmongoc/CMakeFiles/get-crypt_shared.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:182: all] Error 2

Is there a workaround to make it work or I can't really work with mongocxx on my version of ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a different error with `crypt_shared` on Ubuntu 16.04 and build operation would throw error in downloading crypt_shared. So I used `-DMONGOC_TEST_USE_CRYPT_SHARED=FALSE` in cmake arguments and as per file `src/libmongoc/CMakeLists.txt:860` of `mongodb-c-driver-1.23.0`, this means now the build will rely on `mongocryptd` instead. The build went ahead from this particular error.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the beginning of /build/mongodl.py to add your distribution. The line I added below will build a version compatible to 20.04 but you could also try changing it to 22.04.

```
DISTRO_ID_TO_TARGET = {
'ubuntu': {
    '22.*': 'ubuntu2204',
    '21.*': 'ubuntu2004',     # Added this line
    '20.*': 'ubuntu2004',
    '18.*': 'ubuntu1804',
    '16.*': 'ubuntu1604',
    '14.*': 'ubuntu1404',
},
```